# Retrieve multiple records with find_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, controller

The method below works and authenticates a user who has been sent a token-link by email.

```
def login
  inv = Invitation.find_by(email: params[:email])
  if inv && inv.authenticated?(:invitation, params[:id])
    @organization = inv.organization
    unless @organization.nil?
      render 'profiles/show' and return
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Error"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Invalid link"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

This method however seems to assume a person (`inv`) can only exist once in the `Invitation` database. This is not the case, the same person/email address can have multiple records in the database. Therefore, I need to rewrite the method to account for such a situation. How can I do this? Can I use `.all` as added on line 2 below, and use `.each`?

```
def login
  inv = Invitation.find_by(email: params[:email]).all
  if inv
    inv.each do |person|
      if person.authenticated?(:invitation, params[:id])
        @organization = person.organization
        unless @organization.nil?
          render 'profiles/show' and return
        else
          flash[:danger] = "Error"
          redirect_to root_path and return
        end
      end
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid link"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Invalid link"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

---

**Error messages:**

This code produces the error message below but I'm not sure what else than `.all` to use:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for #<Invitation:0x0000000b869ee8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `find_all_by` or `where`

```
inv = Invitation.find_all_by(email: params[:email])
```

or

```
inv = Invitation.where(email: params[:email])
```

Comment: Thanks! Using `inv = Invitation.where('email = ?', params[:email])` seems to have brought me a step further. Tests now produce the error: `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template invitations/login`. Such a view indeed doesn't exist, but given the method it shouldn't require such a view. After all it always directs to either `root` or to `profiles/show`. The test in the old situation passed and is as follows: `get login_path('invalid token')` (login_path routes to the controller method). Any idea about the cause?