# Why is this view template expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, integration-testing

I have a controller method to authenticate a user who has received a link with a token (see method at the bottom). I have an integration test:

```
def test
  get login_path('invalid token')     // Login_path routes to the controller method below.
  assert flash[:danger]
  assert_redirected_to root_path
end
```

This test produces the following error (referring to `get login_path('invalid token')`):

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template invitations/login, application/login with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

The view `invitiations/login` indeed doesn't exist. However, such a view should never be needed given the controller method below (it always either redirects to the `root_path` or renders `profiles/show`). What could be causing this error?

The controller method:

```
def login
  inv = Invitation.where('email = ?', params[:email])
  if inv
    inv.each do |person|
      if person.authenticated?(:invitation, params[:id])
        @organization = person.organization
        unless @organization.nil?
          render 'profiles/show' and return
        else
          flash[:danger] = "Error"
          redirect_to root_path and return
        end
      end
      flash[:danger] = "Invalid link"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Invalid link"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

P.S. The test used to pass, i.e. until I rewrote the controller method to accommodate for multiple `inv`'s (see [Retrieve multiple records with find_by method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34471108)).

Comment: You don't **have** to return after rendering. Just make sure you do not render twice. Rendering once in each branch of an `if`-conditional is ok.

Comment: A remark on a possible source of errors: You iterate over invitations but the item variable is named `person`. I would have expected the variable to be named `invitation`. And `inv` to be `invitations`. Following this kind of naming convention will save you many headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `if inv` - this will still return `true` if no invitations with matching email exist, since `inv` is an ActiveRecord query object. But then the `each` does nothing, i.e. does not redirect or render explicitly. Default render will be invoked and expect a template to exist.

Using `if inv.present?` will fix this.

(Also, you might want to make sure the `inv` collection only contains one result. Redirecting or rendering multiple times in the same request will result in an error.)

Comment: Alternatively, move the redirect on line 14 + 15 one level up, i.e. out of the `each` loop. Then this redirect will only occur if no invited person matches the criteria.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the advice. It works! Was hoping to ask one more question about `render 'profiles/show' and return`: my goal here is that the first time it hits that line, it immediately renders that page and does not further execute the controller method (I added 'and return' with the idea this will take care of that). Because otherwise, as you state, it might render multiple times...? Am I doing this correctly or is it with the current set up possible that it will try to render multiple times?

Comment: If `inv` yields two items for which `person.authenticated?(:invitation, params[:id])` evaluates to false, then you will hit line 15 twice, yes.

Comment: Hope that helps! Since you mentioned that you are satisfied with the answer, please hit that button and accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant line 8. How can I make sure that once it hits the line `render 'profiles/show' and return` that it render that view and stops further iteration over invitations?

Comment: Thx for the accept. Line 8 is fine. It will abort method execution immetdiately after the `render` statement and behave as expected. Personally I will never use `and return` but instead find out what to do first and then have `if elsif else end` conditionals to render or redirect correctly. In your case I'd probably search `inv` for a matching item (using `Enumerable#detect`) and then render it (if found; redirect with error otherwise)